# How to fix permanent EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception in Xcode using SystemC?

Tags: xcode, exc-bad-access, systemc

I want to write SystemC code using the Xcode IDE. I have set it all up and the code I use for testing my Installation builds just fine, but it runs always into Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception, no matter what I do.

I tried to comment everything out, until only the systemc header include and the sc_main was left. When I tried normal c++ code in a different project, to see if it was a general Xcode problem, it work fine and ran into no exception.

I use this generic Hello World-code to test my Installation:

```cpp
#include <systemc>
 //Hello_world is module name
SC_MODULE (hello_world) {
    SC_CTOR (hello_world) {
      // Nothing in constructor
    }

    void say_hello() {
        //Print "Hello World" to the console.
        std::cout << "Hello World.\n";
   }
};

// sc_main in top level function like in C++ main
int sc_main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    hello_world hello("HELLO");
     //Print the hello world
    hello.say_hello();
    return(0);
}
```

After the code ran for a few seconds, it always crashes with: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffeef3ffff8).

**EDIT:**
My Config: 
- SystemC: v2.3.3 
- Xcode: v10.2.1 (10E1001) 
- Compiler: (I ran `gcc --version`) 
    - LLV: v10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4) 
    - c++: v4.2.1 
Im using std=gnu++98 (Compiler Default) as c++language Dialect, everything else ran into build errors.

Comment: Which version of SystemC/Xcode/compiler are you using? Did "gmake check" succeed when building SystemC?

Comment: I did not do gmake/make check on my build, but it built just fine without errors.

Comment: If you used Cmake, make sure to set [CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/variable/CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD.html#variable:CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD) to at least **11** with SystemC 2.3.3 to avoid the issue referenced in my answer.

Comment: And can you try to build SystemC and your model with `CXX=clang++` and `CC=clang` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it! I built SystemC with Cmake following the steps provided in this answer: [Setting up a SystemC project with CMake: undefined reference to `sc_core`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46875731/setting-up-a-systemc-project-with-cmake-undefined-reference-to-sc-core)
. 
In the `CMakeLists.txt` I set `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD` explicitly to `11` and built the project via the command line and `cmake`. 
Thanks for the help:)

Comment: So my answer *was* the key to the problem after all.

Comment: Indeed it was, though it were more the comments you left beneath my question, than the answer you provided, but anyways, thank you :)

Comment: Welcome. My answer explains the root cause for your EXC_BAD_ACCESS. The rest was more guesswork around your environment. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

`EXC_BAD_ACCESS` happens when system can not return from an execution block, such as infinite loop or recursion.

you should take a look at stack trace in the **Debugger navigator** and see which function is getting called and never returns **OR** which function(s) are calling over and over.

Don't forget to run project in **DEBUG** mode. (**NOT release**)

Comment: There are two processes (?) appearing in Thread 1 : 0 malloc_zone_malloc and 126813 _dyld_start, the exception appears in both of them. In 0 it is in line 33 ->  0x7fff69f7adf9 <+99>:  callq  *0x18(%r14) and in 126813 it is in line 15 ->  0x10000e036 <+54>:  movq   -0x8(%rbp), %rdi. This is the only stack trace I get and they are not helping in any way. I hope you know what to do with this.

Comment: These are memory addresses and will change every time you run your project. It would be nicer if you upload your sample project on git to let everyone get closer look.

Comment: The thing is, the "Hello World" Code I postet in my Question IS my sample Projekt. This is literally all the code I use, the the SystemC Library.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SystemC 2.3.2, you might be running into the following issue (on macOS 10.13 or later): http://forums.accellera.org/topic/6079-make-check-return-fail/. This issue is assumed to be fixed in SystemC 2.3.3.

You can avoid it by compiling SystemC 2.3.2 with `../configure --disable-async-updates ...` or by moving to SystemC 2.3.3 and **enabling C++11** (might be the default on a recent Xcode version, you can check the value of the `SC_CPLUSPLUS` macro in your model).