# I got error to set up systemC2.3.3 with visual studio 2017

Tags: systemc

as I stated in the title I got a problem on setting up systemC on my windows pc. So I followed exactly step by step from this link [Installing SystemC for VS2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41990606/installing-systemc-for-vs2013) yet still fail. So I compile my error picture with this question bellow.

---

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXnl6.png)

Answer (score 0):

Check your Runtime Library setting under your project (tutorail) Property Pages...

Right click on the prject (named tutorail) in the Solution Explorer > Properties > Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Code Generation > Runtime Library > Change to "Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd)"

Then rebuild all.

It looks like your SystemC.lib was compiled with /MTd but your project is being compiled with /MDd

I only have VS2019 installed but the solution should be similar for VS2013.